# Proving inequality with parameters

Tags: inequality

How to find all $a$'s for which $$(1+ax)(1+ay)-a\ge 0,$$ for all $x$ and $y$ ?

What to generally do when you have an inequation with parameters which you have to prove for all $x$ and $y$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming $a$ is a constant value and not a function of $x,y$. Then, this inequality isn't true for any $a$ except $a=0$. If we take $x=0$ and $y\to \infty$, any $a< 0$ that is a constant will not satisfy this inequality. On the other hand, if we take $x=0$ and $y\to -\infty$, any $a>0$ that is a constant will not satisfy this inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x,y) = (1+ax)(1+ay)-a$.

We want to find the values of $a$ such that $f(x,y) \ge 0$, for all $x,y$.

If $a=0$, then $f(x,y) = 1$, so $a = 0$ works.

Suppose $a \ne 0$.

Then $f(x,0) = ax + (1-a)$, which is a polynomial of degree $1$, hence has range $\mathbb{R}$. Thus, the values of $f$ are not always nonnegative.

It follows that $a=0$ is the only qualifying value of $a$.

Here's still another way to see it:

If $a \ne 0$, $f(x,x)$ is cubic, hence has range $\mathbb{R}$. So again we see that the values of $f$ are not always nonnegative.

Of course, you don't need to show it twice.

Comment: Thank you. What if we want the inequality to be satisfied for positive x and y?

Comment: If $x,y$ are restricted to nonnegative values, then the inequality holds (for all $x,y \ge 0)$ if and only if $0 \le a \le 1$.

Comment: How do you conclude that a has to be <=1? I guess it's obvious but I can't see it.

Comment: If $a > 1$, then letting $x,y$ both approach zero, the value of $f$ will approach $1-a$.

Comment: If $a < 0$, then letting $y = 1/x$ and letting $x$ approach $\infty$, the value of $f$ will approach $-\infty$.

Comment: If $0 \le a \le 1$, then assuming $x,y \ge 0$, then

$$f(x,y) = (1-a) + ax + ay + a^2xy$$

is a sum of $4$ nonnegative quantities, hence is nonnegative.